# Sencha Touch 2 Ext.create and Ext.Define

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am following sencha touch 2 video tutorial:: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started

In that the instructor uses Ext.Define to define panels. He then loads it into main.js and app.js

But the document thats below that http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app uses Ext.create to create panels on launch

Video worked fine until he was showing simple panels, but when he extended a form panel, it stopped working. Video looks 5 months old and its official video.

Should I stop using Ext.Define and start Ext.create, because the examples do that. Please guide me on this.

Completely confused on this...

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext.define when you are defining a class. You will only use Ext.define once for creating a class.

Ext.create is used to created instances of the defined class using the command above. You will use this multiple times depending on the number of times you need to use the widget.